# How to show message or data only one time while select multiple checkbox in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".choose").click(function(){
            job_type = $(':checked').map(function() { 
                            return this.value; 
                        }).get().join(',');
            category = $("#cat_gory").val();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data:{"job_type":job_type,"category":category},
                url:"type-jobs.php",
                success:function(data){
                    $(".success").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
    <input type="hidden" name="cat_gory" id="cat_gory" value="<?php echo $job_category; ?>" />  
<p class="flchek">
    <input type="checkbox" name="choosetype" value="freelance" class="choose" id="33r">
    <label for="33r">Freelance</label>
</p>
<p class="ftchek">
    <input type="checkbox" name="choosetype" value="full time" class="choose" id="dsf">
    <label for="dsf">Full Time</label>
</p>
<p class="ischek">
    <input type="checkbox" name="choosetype" value="internship" class="choose" id="sdd">
    <label for="sdd">Internship</label>
</p>
<div class="success"></div>
```

type-jobs.php

```
<?php
    include("config.php");
    $job_category = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['category']);
    $job_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['job_type']);
    $tag = explode(",",$job_type);
    foreach($tag as $type)
    {
        $sql_job = mysqli_query($con,"select p.job_title,c.state,c.city from company c inner join jobs p on p.company_name = c.company_name where p.category = '".$job_category."' and job_type='".$type."'");

        $result_job = mysqli_num_rows($sql_job);
        if($result_job > 0)
        {
            while($row_jobs = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_job))
            {
                echo '<h3>'.$row_jobs['job_title'].'</h3>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<p id="c_mm">record not found</p>';
        }
    }
?>
```

In this code I have multiple checkbox. Now, When I click on checkbox to get data through jquery/ajax it return data to me but the problem is if I click on `freelance` checkbox it show me `record not found` again when I click on `full time` then it showing `record not found` as well as `jobs`. Now, I want if data was not found in my database it will show single message to me and if data found then hide message and show database record. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: If the call to the DB is not heavy, produce the HTML on the serer and show/hide the relevant div. No need to ajax then

Comment: `category = $("#cat_gory").val();` I see nothing having `id="cat_gory"`

Comment: see my edit code @Cid

Comment: If I've well understood, the value inside the hidden input with id `cat_gory` is set with the php variable `$job_category` and the php variable `$job_category` value comes from that hidden input. There might be a nonsense there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show `record not found` message only if you don't find any record then you can use a flag in php something like this:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$job_category = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['category']);
$job_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['job_type']);
$found = 0;
$message = '';
$tag = explode(",",$job_type);
foreach($tag as $type)
{
    $sql_job = mysqli_query($con,"select p.job_title,c.state,c.city from company c inner join jobs p on p.company_name = c.company_name where p.category = '".$job_category."' and job_type='".$type."'");

    $result_job = mysqli_num_rows($sql_job);
    if($result_job > 0)
    {
        $found = 1;
        while($row_jobs = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_job))
        {
            $message .= '<h3>'.$row_jobs['job_title'].'</h3>';
        }
    }
}

if(found == 0) {
    $message = '<p id="c_mm">record not found</p>';
}
echo message;
?>
```

Notice `$found` flag here in code. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

NO need to explode the `$jobtype` Use `'jobtype IN('.$jobtype.') '`

```
    <?php
    include("config.php");
    $job_category = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['category']);
    $job_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['job_type']);

    $sql_job = mysqli_query($con,"select p.job_title,c.state,c.city from company c inner join jobs p on p.company_name = c.company_name where p.category = '".$job_category."' and job_type IN('".$jobtype."') ');

       $count = mysqli_num_rows($sql_job);
        $row_data = mysqli_fetch_array($chek_result);
    if($count > 0){
        foreach($row_data as $data){
           $message = '<h3>'.$data['job_title'].'</h3>';
        }
    }else{
       $message = "No Data found";
    }
echo $message;exit;
?>
```